# special chars replaced by browser when download?

Tags: python, django

My django view.py:

```
def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    try:
        self.object = self.get_object()
        file_path = settings.MEDIA_ROOT+self.object.file.name
        chunk_size = 8192
        response = StreamingHttpResponse(FileWrapper(open(file_path), chunk_size),
                content_type=mimetypes.guess_type(file_path)[0])
        response['Content-Length'] = os.stat(file_path).st_size
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="%s"' % smart_str(os.path.basename( file_path ))
        print 'response:', response
        return response
```

Response (from log file):

```
[Wed Aug 03 14:16:54 2016] [error] response: Content-Length: 4194486\r
[Wed Aug 03 14:16:54 2016] [error] Content-Type: image/x-ms-bmp\r
[Wed Aug 03 14:16:54 2016] [error] Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="TestFileName`~@#$%^&*()-_+={}[]|:;<>,.? test   '.bmp
```

But some chars in the file name seems been replaced when downloaded.

[image]

It is the browser's behaviour? Any comments welcomed. Thanks

Comment: Which browser are you using?

Comment: @lapinkoira firefox

Comment: @lapinkoira But chrome is similar

Comment: I am aware of this error in IE https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/949197 but not sure about those browsers